# only refresh shiny plot at launch and if action button is clicked

Tags: r, shiny

I want to render shiny plots on launch and then require clicking the action button to re-render.  I tried to simplify my app to post here.  As you can, see changing the "week" selection triggers a refresh.  how do I suppress all refreshes unless action Is clicked?

```
library(shiny); library(dplyr); library(ggplot2)

#toy data
dates= seq.Date(as.Date("2020-01-01"),as.Date("2020-05-01"),by="days")
set.seed(1)
data = data.frame(date = dates,val = runif(length(dates),50,150))

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("group","Group",choices = LETTERS[1:3]),
      dateRangeInput('dateRangeCal', "Input date range"),
      selectInput("week","shift week",choices = c(0:3)),
      actionButton("action","Submit")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput(outputId = "plot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  observeEvent( input$action, {
    startDate = as.Date("2020-01-01")+days(case_when(
      input$group == "A" ~ 0,
      input$group == "B" ~ 30,
      input$group == "C" ~ 60
    ))
    endDate=startDate+days(60)
    updateDateRangeInput(session = session, 
                         inputId = 'dateRangeCal',
                         label = 'Date range input:',
                         start = startDate,
                         end = endDate
    )

  },ignoreNULL = F)

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    p = data %>%
      filter(date>=input$dateRangeCal[1]+days(input$week)*7,date<=input$dateRangeCal[2]) %>%
      ggplot(.,aes(x=date,y=val))+
      geom_line()
    p
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: `isolate(input$week)` in `renderPlot` should do it.

Comment: I tried it.  That kills the dependency of input$week.  I need the plot to be dependent on it just hold refresh until action is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should do it:

```
server <- function(input, output,session) {

  week <- reactiveVal()

  observeEvent( input$action, {
    week(input$week)
    startDate = as.Date("2020-01-01")+days(case_when(
      input$group == "A" ~ 0,
      input$group == "B" ~ 30,
      input$group == "C" ~ 60
    ))
    endDate=startDate+days(60)
    updateDateRangeInput(session = session, 
                         inputId = 'dateRangeCal',
                         label = 'Date range input:',
                         start = startDate,
                         end = endDate
    )

  },ignoreNULL = F)

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    p = data %>%
      filter(date>=input$dateRangeCal[1]+days(week())*7,date<=input$dateRangeCal[2]) %>%
      ggplot(.,aes(x=date,y=val))+
      geom_line()
    p
  })
}
```

Comment: this appears to work.  if in my actual app, I have multiple additional input selection, I assume I need to call all of them with ReactiveVal() in server and call all those inputs in observeEvent as well?

Comment: This works only the first time. After the action button is clicked the control goes inside the observeEvent() and then without clicking on action button the output plot keeps changing. This is not desirable.

Comment: @LazarusThurston The observeEvent reacts only on clicking the button. That's the purpose of an event observer.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
library(shiny); library(dplyr); library(ggplot2); library(lubridate)

#toy data
dates= seq.Date(as.Date("2020-01-01"),as.Date("2020-05-01"),by="days")
set.seed(1)
data = data.frame(date = dates,val = runif(length(dates),50,150))

ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("group","Group",choices = LETTERS[1:3]),
            dateRangeInput('dateRangeCal', "Input date range"),
            selectInput("week","shift week",choices = c(0:3)),
            actionButton("action","Submit")
        ),
        mainPanel(
            plotOutput(outputId = "plot")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {

    observeEvent(input$action, {
        grp <- isolate(input$group)
        startDate = as.Date("2020-01-01")+days(case_when(
            grp == "A" ~ 0,
            grp == "B" ~ 30,
            grp == "C" ~ 60
        ))
        endDate=startDate+days(60)
        updateDateRangeInput(session = session, 
                             inputId = 'dateRangeCal',
                             label = 'Date range input:',
                             start = startDate,
                             end = endDate
        )

    },ignoreNULL = F)

    output$plot <- renderPlot({
        input$action
        rangecal <- isolate(input$dateRangeCal)
        p = data %>%
            filter(date>=rangecal[1]+days(isolate(input$week))*7,date<=rangecal[2]) %>%
            ggplot(.,aes(x=date,y=val))+
            geom_line()
        p
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```